# Ext.grid.Tree with locked column?

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have a component that is `Ext.grid.Tree` and the `TreeStore`, I want to make the first column locked but seem the `Ext.grid.Tree` is not supported. I don't want to change to another component like `Ext.grid.locked.Grid` or switch to the Modern because it impacted to my design and the functionalities.
Here is my fiddle, please advise!

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3cmd&view/

Answer (score 0):

Set your fiddle to classic instead of modern and change your `Ext.grid.Tree` to `Ext.tree.Panel`. Then, you will able to see the locked columns as the documentation with Modern does not contain configs related to locked. Refer the [fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3cmh&view/editor).

Comment: Thank you. My app uses Modern so cannot use the tree.Panel.